# Is there some easy way to backup MySQL then restore to another environment on rails3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, backup, restore

Rails has `db:migrate`, `db:create`, etc to help rebuild the structure of db, but currently I didn't find any solution that could easily backup & restore on another machine.

We need use some Mysqldump MySQL command, it's a little boring. I would like suggestions for other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it personally, but this gem seems useful: https://github.com/soundevolution/rails-backup-migrate